# best practice for passing objects into other new objects

Tags: php, object-oriented-analysis

Here is my CORE construct:

```
public $objDb;
public $objConfig;
public $configData;
public $objUrl;
public $objController;

public function __construct() {
    $this->objDb = new Dbase();
    $this->objConfig = new Config($this->objDb);
    $this->objUrl = new Url($this->objDb);
    $this->objController = new Controller($this->objUrl, $this->objConfig);
}
```

as you can see I am passing %objDb in to each new class so I dont have to create new class DB in each which means saving connections to database (I think)

but is it good practice or not??
should I in url class create $objDb = new Dbase();
now in URL is

```
public function __construct($db) {
    $this->objDb = $db;
    $this->process();
}
```

UPDATE

thank for response - specially about dependency injection.

One more question Is it possible to do like that
IN CLASS CORE:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->objDb = new Dbase();
    $this->objUrl = new Url();//EMPTY
    $this->objController = new Controller($this->objUrl, $this->objConfig);
}
```

IN CLASS URL

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->objDb = Dbase $db;//declared already in core
    $this->process();
}
```

Comment: [Google: Dependency Injection](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+dependency+injection)

Comment: to me this approach looks `strongly coupled` The second one looks a bit better as that is a bit `loosely coupled` IMO

Comment: To my mind, the properties with the keyword "_public_" are not a good practice.

Comment: Yes I agree - I am planning to change all $obj... into private - thanks for comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use traits, it will be good practice i think.

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: You have to be careful with traits. Some people are cons because they  break the inheritance standard.